# How to add action before Dismissible's onDismissed() action get triggered?

Tags: flutter

I would like to add a small `AlertBox` before the `onDismissed()` action occurs?

So, the user swipe the item form the list to delete it, but just before the action occurs, I want to ask him if he is sure.

Is it possible with the current `Dismissible` widget?

Edit:

```
onDismissed: (direction) {
    final User _deletedItem = this._items[index];

    showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap a button
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          content: Text(
              'Are you sure you want to delete this?'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Cancel'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
              },
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('OK'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    ).then((answer) {
      if (answer == true) {
        setState(() {
          this._items.removeAt(index);
        });

        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text("Deleted"),
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
          ),
        );
      } else {
        setState(() {
          this._items.insert(index, _deletedItem);
        });
      }
    });
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, there is no way to prevent the item from swiping using standard 'Dismissible` as of now.

If you want to achieve what you are looking for you may want to implement your custom way, by making use of `GestureDetector` having child `ListTile` and then listen for `horizontalDrag()` events.

The easier way I would recommend would be to let the user swipe (and let the item go away), after this immediately show a `SnackBar` telling user if he wants to undo that delete action, and you can handle the undo action by putting the item back again in the list.

---

**Edit:**
To perform deletion and undo you can do this,

```
GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = GlobalKey(); // added
List<String> _list = List.generate(10, (index) => "${index}");

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    key: _key, // added
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text("App")),
    body: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _list.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Dismissible(
          key: Key(_list[index]),
          child: ListTile(title: Text(_list[index])),
          background: Container(color: Colors.red),
          onDismissed: (direction) {
            setState(() {
              // added this block 
              String deletedItem = _list.removeAt(index);
              _key.currentState..removeCurrentSnackBar()..showSnackBar(
                SnackBar(
                  content: Text("Deleted \"${deletedItem}\""),
                  action: SnackBarAction(
                    label: "UNDO",
                    onPressed: () => setState(() => _list.insert(index, deletedItem),) // this is what you needed
                  ),
                ),
              );
            });
          },
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Thanks @CopsOnRoad for the suggestion. It is enough for my purpose. You know that 'insertAt' does not exist in Dart 2.1.0 so I used 'insert()' instead? When trying to have the setState execute to get back the deleted item, I get 'A dismissed Dismissible widget is still part of the tree. Make sure to implement the onDismissed handler and to immediately remove the Dismissible widget from the application once that handler has fired.' Suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Actually I meant insert() cause there is no insertAt(). And for undo part, I updated the code, give that a try and let me know if you again face any issue because I haven't tested this code on my own. But I believe it should work.

Comment: I added the source code that I used. Now, the error in emulator is: "A dismissed Dismissable widget is still part of the tree. Make sure to implement the onDismissed handler and to immediately remove the Dismissable widget from the application once that handler has fired"

Comment: Today someone asked the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54303001/flutter-listview-delete-and-undo-operation/54303072#54303072) and I am posting the code of that user with my answer. I updated the answer. Give it a look.

Comment: THANKS @CopsOnRoad

Answer (score 2):

The [confirmDismiss](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Dismissible/confirmDismiss.html) property is what you need.